# How to play Calendar alert sound Chord (default)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I found only classic sounds IDs but I need Chord (default) Calendar Alert. How can I play that sound? Tks

```
#define systemSoundID 1315  
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The calendar alert should be:

```
#define systemSoundID 1005
```

> ↳ [Apple Audio Services : Predefined Sounds](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices)
>   <sub>**Note:** These are undocumented enum values, which
>   means you should not rely on it for AppStore apps.</sub>

**Alternative Method:**

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                 @"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/nano/Alert_Calendar_Haptic.caf"];

SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)fileURL, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(soundID, NULL);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, NULL);
```

You can also include the audio file within your app bundle, or call it from the System Library.

↳ [Currently Available System Sounds (iOS 11)](https://gist.github.com/ParityError/5a691e0cb769b1871f9999293bb22b99)

Comment: Thanks but this is the classic sound. I'm looking for Chord (default) Calendar Alarm available  on IOS 9 . The sound that I need is the same found on IOS Settings->Sounds->Calendar Alerts->Chord (Default) and it's not listed on the link you provided.

Comment: Hi, I just found the solution. Instead of use undocumented enum values I include the sound file in the project and  used  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID before AudioServicesPlaySystemSound and it works ok

Comment: Yes, that works too - I was going to mention that, but didn’t get a chance to edit my answer.